# D3 changes from Version 3.0 to make a circle path of points

Tags: svg, gradient, geometry, d3.js

I am trying to make a gradient path along a circle. Very similar to this example.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4163057

This is D3 version 3. I'm trying to update this to Version 4.
I fixed a few items like 
`d3.ns.prefix.svg` is now `d3.namespaces.svg`
`d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis")` is now `d3.line().interpolateBasis;`

What is killing me is that function `d3.line().interpolateBasis` is returning "line is not a function" `d3.line` and `d3.arc` is returning NaN.

here is a working version of what i am trying to do in D3 Version 3

http:// jsfiddle.net/firetiki/k3q0d848/

Here is the code for D3 Version 4 with the changes for v4 that does not work. I am getting line is not a function in the console.

http://jsfiddle.net/firetiki/9nwwgywz/

Any help would be appreciated. Maybe I am missing another change in the version update?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado. yes. my code would be helpful. thanks. forgot to post the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `interpolateBasis` in D3 v4: https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#curves

So, change your line function to this:

```
var line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveBasis);
```

Here is your fiddle using D3 v4: http://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/fro6Lu2x/

Answer (score 1):

Mike Bostock has now updated to D3 version 4

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4163057